# skipping a line while reading a file with a for loop

Tags: python, file-io, for-loop, iterator

I am trying to figure out a way to skip the next two lines in a file if a condition in the first line is true.   Any ideas on a good way to do this?  Here's what I have so far...

```
def main():
    file = open(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\test2.txt', 'r+')
    ctr = 1
    for current_line in file:
        assert ctr<3
        if current_line[0:6] == str("001IU"):
            pass
        else:
            if ctr == 1 and current_line[9:11] == str("00"):
                do something...
                ctr += 1
            elif ctr == 1 and current_line[9:11] != str("00"):
                pass #I want it to skip the next two lines in the loop
            elif ctr == 2:
                do something...
                ctr = 1
            else:
                raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or above, use

```
next(file)
next(file)
```

to skip two items of the iterator `file`, i.e. the next two lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.next()
file.next()
```

i'd do this way...

Comment: If i want to see only data between from line number 7 to what is before ( total line count of file - 4 ) line while i was reading that particular file