# skip 2 lines after a match in python

Tags: python

I am trying to skip 2 lines after I got a match, as shown here.
I have tried [skipping a line while reading a file with a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003293/skipping-a-line-while-reading-a-file-with-a-for-loop) 
which is giving me error:

```
 fin.next()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

My complete code, input, output and expected output is pasted. I am a newbie. Kindly help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3     fin.next()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
import sys
inp = str(sys.argv[1])
print(inp)

mesh = []
with open(inp, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith("NQ"):
            nq = int(line[6:].strip())
        if line.startswith("NT"):     # Number of elements
            nt = int(line[6:].strip())
        if line.startswith("NM"):     # Number of type
            nm = int(line[6:].strip())
        if line.startswith("IREL"):
            irel = line[6:].strip()
        if line.startswith("NSPIN"):
            nspin = line[6:].strip()


# Getting the Mesh
        if line.startswith("MESH-TYPE EXPONENTIAL"):
            fin.readline(1)
            for i in range(nm):
                mesh = line.split()
                print(mesh)
```

input:

```
*******************************
GLOBAL SYSTEM PARAMETER
NQ                 2
NT                 2
NM                 2
IREL               3
NSPIN              1
*******************************************************************************
MESH INFORMATION
MESH-TYPE EXPONENTIAL 
   IM       R(1)                  DX              JRMT       RMT             JRWS       RWS
    1  1.00000000000000E-06  2.02543202000000E-02  716  1.94855715851499E+00  721  2.15458905088026E+00
    2  1.00000000000000E-06  2.03289742000000E-02  713  1.94855715851499E+00  721  2.27356898717917E+00
*******************************************************************************
```

Output:

```
['MESH-TYPE', 'EXPONENTIAL']
['MESH-TYPE', 'EXPONENTIAL']
```

Expected Output:

```
1  1.00000000000000E-06  2.02543202000000E-02  716  1.94855715851499E+00  721  2.15458905088026E+00
2  1.00000000000000E-06  2.03289742000000E-02  713  1.94855715851499E+00  721  2.27356898717917E+00
```

Comment: As the accepted answer suggests there use `next(fin)` not `fin.next()`.

Comment: None brings then to the next line

Comment: Not sure what are you doing right now, but something like this http://ideone.com/bmYY88 works fine for me.

Comment: no idea what I am missing...but just not getting it skip the lines

Comment: Can you post your actual code? I can't find any calls to `next()` in your code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks, can you kindly check https://bpaste.net/show/72c583b7ce39 ?

Comment: Try: http://ideone.com/hHd1eD